# Difference between verifyText and verifyTextPresent in Selenium

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests

I'm trying to build a test using Selenium IDE and I want to check that a certain `<div>` block contains the correct text. What assertion should I use? What is the difference between `text` and `textPresent`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`*TextPresent` commands check for the presence of the text in the entire page. This can often lead to false positives, and is not generally advised. `*Text` commands require a locator, and the text of the element located is directly compared. Another advantage is that a failure will give you details of the expected and actual text, whereas the former commands simply return true/false.

You will need a way to locate your `<div>` element, which is easiest if it has an `id` attribute. Check the official documentation for locator strategies: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#locating-elements

Comment: Thanks a lot! This confirms that *Text was the assertion I needed.